# how do you add an event to a dropdown list added in this way @Html.DropDownList("List")?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how do you add one or more events to a dropdownlist added in this way

@Html.DropDownList("List") ?

Comment: use another overload with htmlAttributes or use jquery... http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: how do you use another overload with htmlAttributes

Comment: Just to be sure: you're using mvc, or webforms ?

Comment: in this project I  am using  mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are comfortable using jQuery:**, try this:

```
     $("#DropDownListID").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        //Do whatever you want to do on selection changes here
     });
```

Comment: is it possible to insert the event in here @Html.DropDownList("List") ?  if yes how

Comment: Yes, but you should use Unobtrusive JavaScript as far as possible. See this for more detail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownList("PageItemDD", (SelectList)ViewBag.itemsPerPage, new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/List?ipp=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

The `new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/List?ipp=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" }` part (the 3rd parameter to DropDownList) is the html attribute(s). In this case I have a `onchange` that loades this page: `/List?ipp= the value of the dropdownlist`